# Proper datatype for month in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to store month like JAN,FEB and soon in database. What datatype should I use? because if I use varchar, when I display it, it won't sort properly. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TINYINT is as the month and have another table with columns month_id, Month_name

where you place

```
1     JAN
2     FEB
etc...
```

the sorting etc will work fine. when you want to display, have a simple inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Just store it as a complete date (perhaps always using the first as the day)  and use the database functions [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) if you only need part of it. This makes using that field much easier as you can still do range queries, etc.

Comment: Do you mean I need to use DATETIME data type?

Comment: get this error : Incorrect datetime value: 'JAN' for column 'month'

Answer (score 0):

Store months number in database.
i.e.  For JAN store 01, FEB store 02 and so on..
Take Datatype TINY INT for your field.

OR another solution you can try:

Take datatype DATE for your field.
Use this type of query: SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2014-03-27','%b');

[DATE_FORMAT_MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)